# Renaming a DLL causes the code using it to crash

Tags: c++, dll

I have a DLL which is written in native C++. The Visual Studio project name is `MyDll` and it compiles to a file called `MyDll.dll` in the output directory.

After compilation, I rename it to `MyDll2.dll`. (This example seems silly but I have a good reason for renaming it.)

A second project, written in C++/CLI, uses this DLL.

At compile time, this project references `MyDll.lib` (generated when MyDll is compiled) to be able to use classes defined in the dll.

At runtime, to load the DLL, I call LoadLibrary, passing it the full path of the file `C:\...\MyDll2.dll` (it's actually in the same folder). It loads successfully, as shown by LoadLibrary's return value.

At the first occurence in code where I use a class defined in the DLL (just declaring an object on the stack), it crashes with an `SEHException` (these exceptions give no information whatsoever about the cause of the crash...)

This only happens if I do the renaming step. If I leave it as `MyDll.dll` and call LoadLibrary on that file, everything works fine. So it is obviously due to the renaming.

Any ideas why? Am I not allowed to rename the DLL?

**(EDIT: clarifying by giving more details)**

Comment: Does your application have a handle to that DLL (use Procexp to tell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a dll the linker also generates a lib-file which you use to link with in your executable. This lib file contains the dll-name from which the exported functions and data are being imported. So your executable has references to originally name dll in it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you renaming a DLL after it's been loaded? You should never rename a DLL after you called LoadLibrary. I'm surprised the OS would even allow you to do that.

Comment: I don't. I rename it after it has been compiled, before running anything.

Answer (score 1):

> in which case I would have to recompile to change the file name

Yes you do, the LoadLibrary() argument must be changed when you rename the DLL.  Fix your real problem, it doesn't sound like you check the return value of LoadLibrary() at all.  Throw a Win32Exception when it returns NULL.

Comment: Obviously the argument is the actual name of the DLL... It loads fine, I do check the return value, which indicates success. But later when I use a class from the DLL, it fails with SEHException.

Comment: I've got nothing to look at.  Improve your question by posting some code snippets and the value of the exception's ToString().

Comment: I added details to the question. The ToString of the exception contains almost no info except the error code meaning 'unknown error' (I'll post it later if necessary). I'll also add snippets when I'm back on the pc with the code. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't give us what is needed to help you.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Edwin. The lib file directions to exported functions and also contains the name of dll which was at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone will be reading this after a year, but why was OP even LoadLibrary'ing this renamed dll when it was already statically linked? This is 2 different things. I think OP's app was crashing due to lack of MyLib.dll, required after static linkage, and LoadLibrary has nothing to do with it, OP could as well omit LoadLibrary of MyLib2.dll and the result would be exactly the same. Only thing i can't explain is unknown error mentioned.